# What is the point of a = a;? Analysing the jQuery source

Tags: javascript, jquery

From the jQuery [1.7rc1 source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7rc1.js) (lines 1822-24):

```
if ( jQuery.isArray( name ) ) {
        name = name;
}
```

What's the point of having `name = name`? Could the two `name`s be different?

Comment: The identifier name `"name"` is either bound to a value in the current lexical environment or not. It cannot be bound to two distinct values.

Comment: Btw, assignments to properties (like `foo.bar = foo.bar;`) can make sense if that property is an accessor property with an defined setter function. (For instance `iframe.src = iframe.src;` will relaod the IFRAME.)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Could you please give an example of that?

Comment: @Randomblue He just did, didn't he?

Comment: @GolezTrol: Yeah, he edited his answer just before I asked.

Comment: @Randomblue Here: http://jsfiddle.net/z8CFd/1/

Comment: @Randomblue No, this is awesome: http://jsfiddle.net/z8CFd/2/ `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is added for readability. The name should be an array, which it isn't always. In some cases it it converted to an array, but in this case, it is good 'as is'.

The whole fragment:

```
            // Support space separated names
            if ( jQuery.isArray( name ) ) {
                name = name;
            } else if ( name in thisCache ) {
                name = [ name ];
            } else {

                // split the camel cased version by spaces
                name = jQuery.camelCase( name );
                if ( name in thisCache ) {
                    name = [ name ];
                } else {
                    name = name.split( " " );
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

The statement is probably added to be consistent with the other statements. The `name = name` can be omitted, but it's probably kept to clearly show the function of the block.

There is no way that a variable with exactely the same name hold different values, next to each other.

*Code*

```
// Support space separated names
if ( jQuery.isArray( name ) ) {
   name = name;
} else if ( name in thisCache ) {
    name = [ name ];
} else {
    // split the camel cased version by spaces
   name = jQuery.camelCase( name );
   if ( name in thisCache ) {
       name = [ name ];
   } else {
       name = name.split( " " );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's just so there's consistency between what all the branching if-statements do (they all assign `name`).